# How to access a folder in a project which is running on tomcat

Tags: java, gwt

I have a folder in my projects war folder, So its running fine in development mode .
But when i try to run the same application on my localHost.
It says "FileNotFound".

I use this path which works for development mode:
String filePath = "mydata/";

Now what path I will be using when running on tomcat?

I also tried to put the  folder in Tomcat Bin Folder and using same filePath,But no luck!

Please guide.

Code:

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        GreetingService {

```
String filePath = "./cdata/";
```

public CountryDTO getCountryDataFromFile(String selectedCountry)
    {

```
    Gson mydata = new Gson();
    CountryDTO dto = null;
    System.out.println("test");
    try 
    {
        String line;
        File f = new File(filePath + selectedCountry + ".txt");

        BufferedReader jsonReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
```

///RPC call

void getJSONDataFromFile(String mAdministrativeArea, AsyncCallback asyncCallback);

//Client Side , from where my code is been called

mAdministrativeAreaA.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler(){

```
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> changedSubRegion) {
            mAdministrativeArea= changedSubRegion.getValue();
            System.out.println("going to rpc");
            addrService.getJSONDataFromFile(mAdministrativeArea, new AsyncCallback<CountryDTO>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(CountryDTO json) {


                    json.setFmt( selectedCountry.getFmt() );

                    GUIfromFormat(json, ResultType.STATE_OR_PROVINCE);
                }
```

Comment: Did you tried  `String filePath = "./mydata/";` ?

Comment: Your development-mode is not on your localhost?

Comment: Please show us how you are accessing the file

Comment: Are you using servlet?

Comment: tried :  filePath = "./mydata/", but still not working , Should I place this folder in war folder or my tomcat Bin folder? At the moment its in both places

Comment: my development mode is in my local

Comment: then what are you using man? please add more information to dig in problem

Comment: I am using GWT (Google Web Toolkit)..

Comment: Added a server side code, from where I am reading the files(which are in my war folder)

Answer (score 0):

When you run your webapp in development mode, most likely your current folder is the project root.

When you run your webapp live (meaning not from your IDE), you cannot guess the current folder as it may vary from OS to OS, server to server etc.

You can use [ServletContext.getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) to find out the path/location to the underlying file of a path.

If you call:

```
String path = ServletContext.getRealPath("/");
```

This will return the root folder of your web application, the folder which contains the special `"WEB-INF"` folder (and optionally the `"META-INF"` folder). Knowing this folder is a good starting point, you can navigate starting from here (either up - parent, or down - child folder).

Of course if the file/resource you try to access is outside of the web folder, it will not be available during production, you have to place it under your web folder in order so it will get deployed along with your web application code.

### Getting the `ServletContext`

You said this is the server side of an async call. Then it is a servlet. I don't see all your code, it might be a `RemoteServiceServlet`?

Whatever is the case, if there is an underlying `Servlet`, you can get the `ServletContext` from it (via `HttpServletRequest.getServletContext()`), then you have `ServletContext.getRealPath()`.

Also you can get the `ServletContext` using a `ServletContextListener`. Here is how to do it: [Getting `ServletContext` at webapp startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480675/accessing-url-mappings-of-a-servlet-in-tomcat-with-only-static-functions/25480806#25480806)

### Another approach

If you place your files/resources inside your source folder, you can access them  `ClassName.getResource()` and `ClassName.getResourceAsStream()` methods. These methods will always give you back the proper resource no matter if the code (Java class) is coming from a `.class` file or from a jar file etc.

Putting your resources next to your class files also has the benefit that your resources will automatically move with the code (they will be automatically deployed when you redeploy your code).

Comment: thanks , ServletContext   is not resolvable , You can have a look on my code above, where i am trying to get the path

Comment: The question is where is your code called from? From a Servlet? From a Listener?

Comment: Using async call.. just edited my code, Please have a look..(Its GWT framework)

Comment: Added more info about getting the `ServletContext`.